# Image preview not showing when creating a collection/single type?

Tags: strapi

After adding an image to my collection/single type the preview image Strapi shows is not displaying [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4F9VE.png).

I inspected the img src and the src address is correct and the url correctly takes me to where the image is stored [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLfxk.png).

Does anyone know why / how to get the preview image working??

I am using the following:

- strapi - v4.1.3
- strapi-provider-upload-azure-storage - v2.0.0
- node - v16.8.0
- Azure storage and CDN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the following to my ./config/middlewares.js file:

```
module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
          'img-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', `${AZURE_CDN_URL}`],
          'media-src': ["'self'", 'data:', 'blob:', `${AZURE_CDN_URL}`],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Just a comment, you can use an environment variable that points to storage URL if you don't make use of a CDN

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this issue when using other cloud provider, eg. Cloudinary. I found that this is a security middleware issues, anyone facing this issue on other providers can go to https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/providers

Inside each provider guide, there's a section of:

**Security Middleware Configuration**

Due to the default settings in the Strapi Security Middleware you will need to modify the contentSecurityPolicy settings to properly see thumbnail previews in the Media Library. You should replace strapi::security string with the object bellow instead as explained in the middleware configuration documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I fixing that error by using this settings:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => [
      "strapi::errors",
    
      {
        name: "strapi::security",
        config: {
          contentSecurityPolicy: {
            directives: {
              'connect-src': ['self', 'http:', env("SUPABASE_URL")],
              'img-src': ['self', 'data:', 'blob:', , env("SUPABASE_URL"), 'https://dl.airtable.com'],
             
            },
          },
        },
      },
      "strapi::cors",
      "strapi::poweredBy",
      "strapi::logger",
      "strapi::query",
      "strapi::body",
      "strapi::session",
      "strapi::favicon",
      "strapi::public",
    ];
```

into `middleware.js`

After restarting thumbnail preview start working properly.